# Identify variables (dummies) coded as 1/2 and transform to 0/1

Tags: r, data-manipulation

In a larger dataset I would like to identify variables (dummies) coded as 1/2 and transform them to 0/1. They might contain missings.

```
## test dataset:
df <- data.frame(
  c(1,2,2,1,2,NA,NA,1,2,NA),
  c(1,2,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,2),
  c(0,1,NA,1,1,0,NA,1,NA,0),
  c(0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0))
names(df) <- c("A","B","C","D")
```

Columns A and B should be transformed, C and D should remain the same.

```
## attempts:
df2 <- select(df, function(x) {x %in% c(1,2,NA)})
df2 <- sapply(df, function(x) {(x %in% c(1,2,NA))})
```

Once identified (which I could not achieve yet), I would like to transform these columns like this: 1 to 0, 2 to 1. In the end I aim to have df2 in the same dimensions as df.

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In each column check if all non-NA values are in 1:2 and if so subtract 1 from each value.

```
library(dplyr)
df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(across(where(~ all(na.omit(.) %in% 1:2)), ~ .x - 1))
```

or using only base R:

```
ok <- sapply(df, function(x) all(na.omit(x) %in% 1:2))
df2 <- replace(df, ok, df[ok] - 1)
```

A cautionary note that there is an ambiguity inherent in the question (although fortunately none of the columns in the question have this ambiguity) -- namely, that if a column contains only 1 or only 1 and NA then we cannot know if it represents a 0:1 or 1:2 column.    To resolve the ambiguity the code above assumes the former but if there were any columns in the set returned by the following then if this default does not resolve it properly then it will be necessary to use application knowledge to resolve the ambiguity.

```
which(sapply(df, function(x) all(na.omit(x) == 1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can subtract 1 or test if equal `2`

```
i <- colSums(df == 2, na.rm=TRUE) > 0 & colSums(df == 0, na.rm=TRUE) == 0
#i <- sapply(df, function(x) all(x[!is.na(x)] %in% 1:2)) #Alternative
#Will not work in case there is only 1 in the column

df[, i] <- df[, i] - 1
#df[, i] <- +(df[, i] == 2) #Alternative

df
#    A B  C D
#1   0 0  0 0
#2   1 1  1 1
#3   1 1 NA 1
#4   0 0  1 1
#5   1 1  1 1
#6  NA 0  0 0
#7  NA 1 NA 0
#8   0 0  1 1
#9   1 1 NA 1
#10 NA 1  0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

if you'd like to do it conditionally by `tidyverse` ;

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
mutate(A = case_when(A==1 ~ 0,
                     A==2 ~ 1),
       B = case_when(B==1 ~ 0,
                     B==2 ~ 1))
```

***output;***

```
       A     B     C     D
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     0     0     0     0
 2     1     1     1     1
 3     1     1    NA     1
 4     0     0     1     1
 5     1     1     1     1
 6    NA     0     0     0
 7    NA     1    NA     0
 8     0     0     1     1
 9     1     1    NA     1
10    NA     1     0     0
```

Answer (score 0):

You just use `ifelse`

```
df$A = ifelse(df$A == 1, 0, 1)
df$B = ifelse(df$A == 1, 0, 1)
    A B  C D AA
1   0 0  0 0  0
2   1 1  1 1  1
3   1 1 NA 1  1
4   0 0  1 1  0
5   1 1  1 1  1
6  NA 0  0 0 NA
7  NA 1 NA 0 NA
8   0 0  1 1  0
9   1 1 NA 1  1
10 NA 1  0 0 NA
```